# Disabling click event on angular material row for specific values

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have material table similar to this:

```
<md-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container mdColumnDef="a">
      <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> a </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"><a routerLink="{{element.number}}"> {{element.a}} </a></md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container mdColumnDef="b">
      <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> b </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"> {{element.b}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <md-header-row *mdHeaderRowDef="['a', 'b']"></md-header-row>
    <md-row *mdRowDef="let row; columns: ['a', 'b']" (click)="selectRow(row)"></md-row>
  </md-table>
```

I would like to disable click event in some cases, for example, when element.b cell have some value.
i'm using latest versions of angular and material...

Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using angular Change Detection.

Please refer to: [A Comprehensive Guide to Angular onPush Change Detection Strategy](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)

In order to disable the clickable cell you can do this:

```
   <md-row *mdRowDef="let row; columns: ['a', 'b']" [disabled]='logic == true' (click)="selectRow(row)"></md-row>
```

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it for matMenu or matSelect inserted in mat table row (td) - which opened and invoke whole row click if you have whole row click set, need to control click on them by

*.html

```
<button
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="actionOptionsMenu"
  mat-icon-button
  (click)="handleActionsClick(actionOptionsMenu, $event)"
>
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>

<mat-menu
  #actionOptionsMenu="matMenu"
 ...
```

and *.ts foo

```
handleActionsClick(mySelect, event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  mySelect.open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to achieve this.

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.innerHTML === " 9.0122 ") {
      event.stopPropagation(); //swallow event and prevent it from bubbling up
    } else {
      console.log('@HostListener: ', event.target.innerHTML)
    }
```

Notice in the Stackblitz click events are logged in the console on everything but the `Weight` column with a value of `9.0122`

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgnzv4?embed=1&file=app/table-basic-example.ts